# Method Completely Ignores for loops:

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

After running my program I noticed that all values of my array are equal to one and after running the debugger I noticed that my for loops that should have populated the array are simply skipped over but I have absolutly no idea as to why. Could someone please tell me what I've done wrong?

The program reaches this line:

```
for (a = a; a >= 1000; a++) // Adds all prime numbers 1 through 1000 to primeA[];
```

and then jumps to:

```
for (int k = 0; k < primeA.Length; k++)
```

Complete code:

```
class calcPrime
{
    /* @Method: isPrimeSET
     * @param: int a, int b
     * @return: true / false
     * @ Builds a list of primes and sorts them into a multi dimensional array. 
     */
    public int[,] isPrimeSet(int a, int b)
    {
        int[,] primeNumArray = new int[999, 999]; // Prime Multi Array 1000 slots in each array
        int[] primeA = new int[999]; // All prime numbers a 1 to 1000
        int[] primeB = new int[999]; // All prime numbers b 1 to 1000

        ArrayList dumpArrayA = new ArrayList(); // None prime numbers
        ArrayList dumpArrayB = new ArrayList(); // None prime numbers

        for (a = a; a >= 1000; a++) // Adds all prime numbers 1 through 1000 to primA[];
        {
            if (isPrime(a) == true)
            {
                int i = 0; // Index of primeA
                primeA[i] = a; // Add primes to a
                i++;
            }

            else // Stores none prime numbers
            {
                int m = 0;
                dumpArrayA.Add(m);
                m++;
            }

            for (b = b; b >= 1000; b++) // Adds all prime number 1 through 1000 to primeB[];
            {
                if (isPrime(b) == true)
                {
                    int j = 0; // Index of primeB
                    primeB[j] = b; // Add primes to b
                    j++;
                }

                else
                {
                    int n = 0;
                    dumpArrayB.Add(n);
                    n++;

                }

            }
        }

        // Merge primesA[] and primesB[];
        for (int k = 0; k < primeA.Length; k++)
        {
            primeNumArray[k, 0] = primeA[k];
            primeNumArray[k, 1] = primeB[k];
        }

        // Print Contents of PrimeNumArray
        for (int l = 0; l >= primeNumArray.Length; l++) {
            Console.WriteLine(primeNumArray[l, l]);
        } 

        return primeNumArray;

    }
```

Else statements and dump arrays added in vain attempt at making the program work. Also I know I assigned a variable to the same variable in the for loops, I wanted the value to be set wherever the user chooses when the method is called.

Comment: Is `for (a = a; a >= 1000; a++)` meant to be that or `for(a = 1; a >= 1000; a++)`?

Comment: a >= 1000 or a <= 1000

Comment: a is intended to be whatever value is passed to the method when it is called in the main .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many mistake there !!

I managed to correct your code

here is your corrected code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;

namespace Prime_number
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] k = isPrimeSet(1, 1);
            Console.Read();
        }

        public static int[,] isPrimeSet(int a, int b)
        {
            int[,] primeNumArray; // Prime Multi Array 1000 slots in each array
            ArrayList primeA = new ArrayList(); // All prime numbers a 1 to 1000
            ArrayList primeB = new ArrayList(); // All prime numbers b 1 to 1000

            ArrayList dumpArrayA = new ArrayList(); // None prime numbers
            ArrayList dumpArrayB = new ArrayList(); // None prime numbers
            int i = 0;
            int m = 0;
            int j = 0; // Index of primeB
            int n = 0;

            for (a = 1; a <= 1000; a++) // Adds all prime numbers 1 through 1000 to primA[];
            {
                if (isPrime(a) == true)
                {
                    // Index of primeA
                    primeA.Add( a); // Add primes to a
                    i++;
                }
                else // Stores none prime numbers
                {
                    dumpArrayA.Add(m);
                    m++;
                }
            }

            for (b = 1; b <= 1000; b++) // Adds all prime number 1 through 1000 to primeB[];
            {
                if (isPrime(b) == true)
                {
                    primeB.Add(b); // Add primes to b
                    j++;
                }
                else
                {
                    dumpArrayB.Add(n);
                    n++;
                }

            }
            primeNumArray= new int[primeA.Count,2];
            // Merge primesA[] and primesB[];
            for (int k = 0; k < primeA.Count; k++)
            {
                primeNumArray[k, 0] = (int)primeA[k];
                primeNumArray[k, 1] = (int)primeB[k];
            }

            // Print Contents of PrimeNumArray
            for (int l = 0; l <= primeNumArray.GetLength(0)-1; l++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(primeNumArray[l, 0] + "  " + primeNumArray[l, 1]);
            }

            return primeNumArray;

        }


        static bool isPrime(int num)
        {
            bool bPrime = true;
            int factor = num / 2;
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 2; i <= factor; i++)
            {
                if ((num % i) == 0)

                    bPrime = false;
            }
            return bPrime;
        }
    }
}
```

Give it a try :) ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think index of array seems incorrect,

```
        if (isPrime(a) == true)
        {
            int i = 0; // Index of primeA
            primeA[i] = a; // Add primes to a
            i++;
        }
```

Isn't that changing only primeA[0] value? And for primeB array

```
            int j = 0; // Index of primeB
            primeB[j] = b; // Add primes to b
            j++;
```

Maybe you should define i and j out of loop.

Comment: OK, I'll give it a try. Thanks.